# Unrecognised database format exception

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, aceoledb

I have already successfully connect my programs to my database.
Then I edit my database in `Access`, and after that when running my program, I get  an error notice that `UNRECOGNISED DATABASE FORMAT`.

Then I try to make new database and connect to vb.net but it failed again.
I don't know where the fault is because I didn't change anything in my code.
I already use provider `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0` and file extension in `.accdb` format.

Comment: Improved grammar and formatting (mostly line breaks), added `aceoledb` tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First possibility: the database might have been corrupted. Try compact and repair.

Second possibility: inadvertently the database format was changed, if that is the case you can always "save as" a lower version like 2003 or 2010.